# Открытие определенной страницы в зависимости от города пользователя

Tags: php, drupal, редирект, геолокация

Есть одностраничный сайт на Drupal (хотя CMS наверное не имеет значения) нужно чтобы в зависимости от города открывалась определенная страница.
Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: А что вы уже сделали, кроме того, что сюда запостили вопрос? Неужели поиск по интернету не дал ни одного решения?

Comment: В основном рекомендуют мультисайтинг, но поскольку у меня одностраничный сайт, может есть возможность реализовать внутри сайта.

Comment: вбил ваши слова из вопроса в поиск и сразу нашёл вот такой модуль: https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip , никаких мультисайтингов не встретил

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно использовать сервис [http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=Ваш_IP](http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88_IP), и дальше парсить нужные данные.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$res = file_get_contents('http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip='.$ip);
```

Comment: Ответ хорошо, но стоит добавить `timeout` для запроса и наче, при падение сервиса упадёт и сайт.